# $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x+1}dx$

Tags: integration

What results?

$$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x+1}dx$$

my try : $u= \tan \frac{x}{2 } $

but : What is the short way?

Comment: Substitution $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-u$.

Comment: i think the $$\tan(\frac{x}{2})$$ is the right way

Comment: a possible result for the indefinite integral is $$\frac{x}{2}-\log \left(\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\sin x+\cos x+1 &=& 1+\sin x+\cos x \\
  &=& (\sin\frac{x}{2}+\cos\frac{x}{2})^2+(\cos^2\frac{x}{2}-\sin^2\frac{x}{2}) \\
  &=& (\sin\frac{x}{2}+\cos\frac{x}{2})2\cos\frac{x}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
We have by substitution $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-u$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin u}{\sin u+\cos u+1}du
&=&
\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x+1}dx\\
&=&
\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}-\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{(\sin\frac{x}{2}+\cos\frac{x}{2})2\cos\frac{x}{2}}dx\\
&=&
\frac12\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{(\cos\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2})}{\cos\frac{x}{2}}dx\\
&=&
\frac12\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 1-\tan\frac{x}{2}dx\\
&=&
\frac{\pi}{4}+\ln\cos\frac{x}{2}\Big|_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&=&
\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac12\ln2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: @DavidQuinn Final number is corrected. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 4):

Hint... You can write the integral as $$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sin\frac x2}{\sin\frac x2+\cos \frac x2} dx$$

Then consider $$J=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cos\frac x2}{\sin\frac x2+\cos \frac x2} dx$$

Now work out $J-I$ and $J+I$

Comment: Unfortunately, with substitution upper limit in $J$ will change to $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @MyGlasses...What substitution?

Comment: $I+J=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cos\frac x2+\sin \frac{x}{2}}{\sin\frac x2+\cos \frac x2} dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} dx$

$J-I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cos\frac x2-\sin \frac{x}{2}}{\sin\frac x2+\cos \frac x2} dx$
now??!!

Comment: The first primitive is $x$ and the second is $2\ln|\sin\frac x2+\cos\frac x2|$

Comment: @MyGlasses. I have used half-angle formulas to change the original integrand.